# How to uniquely identify a notebook and the wireless access point it connects?

Tags: security, networking, wireless, identifier, mac-address

There are a notebook A and a wireless access point B.

The scenario is:
1. the notebook A successfully connects to the wireless access point B.
2. the notebook A sends a "hello" message to my server.
3. my server receives this message. My question is how my server knows this message is sent by the notebook A (not other notebooks) via the wireless access point B (not via other wireless access points). Here who uses the notebook A is not my concern.

I am thinking a rough solution like this. Let my server know the notebook A's CPU serial number and the wireless access point's mac address. Any computer sending message to my server needs to report its CPU serial number and wireless gateway mac address. If these two are the same as those kept by my server, then pass.

I understand those two can be faked also. Please advise better solutions. Thank you so much.

Comment: It's not clear what you're doing. What do you mean by "to confirm"? What is your outer problem? Do you trust the notebook to identify itself?

Comment: Does your server have access to management information from the AP (e.g. via SNMP) so it can query the association table?

Comment: The answer given is going to depend on your operational needs. If you need something crazy-secure, you could look at public keys associated with both A and B in your scenario, where A requests signed data from B, signs it, and passes it to C for verification. Also, you're not at the "what language should I use" stage, since you're designing infrastructure.

Comment: Without specially designed and crafted tools (see tbert's comment) 'unique identification' is wide field for research. An interessing article around this can be found here: https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2010/01/primer-information-theory-and-privacy It is referring to a more practical approach to be tried out here: https://panopticlick.eff.org/

Comment: This question is probably better suited for [security.stackexchange.com](http://security.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

Set up your access point to run WPA enterprise. Run the RADIUS server on your server. Optionally tunnel the traffic from the AP to the server. Issue unique credentials to each possible client, possibly certificate based.

With the RADIUS information and a "secure" (i.e. tunneled or direct cabled link) from the AP you can unambiguously and securely identify the wireless clients on the server, provided you trust the whole machine, the AP and the intermediate links.